# NavLink component stays active?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

A navlink to homepage always stays active. Other 2 navlinks work correctly and only added an active style when chosen. Is there any problem with routes or function that changes the active link?

```
const activeStyles = {
  color: 'green',
};

<ul className="flex gap-8">
  <li>
    <NavLink
      to={"/"}
      className="text-xs text-gray-400 hover:text-white"
      style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyles : undefined)}
    >
      Main
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink
      to={"posts"}
      className="text-xs text-gray-400 hover:text-white"
      style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyles : undefined)}
    >
      My Posts
    </NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
    <NavLink
      to={"new"}
      className="text-xs text-gray-400 hover:text-white"
      style={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? activeStyles : undefined)}
    >
      Add post
    </NavLink>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: after clicking on the add post Navlink, main still stays active]

Answer (score 2):

For react-router v6, if you want your root route (`"/"`) to be active only at this route, you should add an `end` prop to `<NavLink>`:

```
<NavLink to="/" end>
  Main
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use exact key work in Navlink like this:

```
<NavLink to='/' exact={true}>
   Main
 </NavLink>
```

because'/' is active for all routes that's why you are getting this.

Comment: I think exact was removed from router v6 so it doesn't work in my case

Comment: For v6 you can use: If the end prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to render a link that is only active at the website root and not any other URLs, you can use:                           <NavLink to="/" end>
  link 
</NavLink>